# JS How can I convert a serialized object to an Array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, serialization

Using `jquery.nestable.min.js`, I get a the following output:

```
[{"id":32},{"id":29},{"id":30}]
```

This current output is coming from the following code:

```
const myList = JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize'));
```

I need it to simply be:

```
32, 29, 30
```

End result is that I would like to read a normal array in PHP. I'm looking to either convert `myList` to an array in Javascript and POST that array, or convert the current version of the object to an array inside PHP, whichever is most effective.

I've tried to use json_decode in PHP, but I get empty values. So I figured if I can just convert to a normal Array before sending it off to PHP, then it would be less of a hassle.

Thank you.

This may be duplicated, in which case, please point me to the best answer

Comment: I would suggest giving `json_decode` in PHP another try... Check the value PHP is receiving before trying to decode it (you can use `print_r`), and try to figure out why it's returning empty values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether you want an array (per your title), or literally `32, 29, 30` per your post:

```js
console.log([{"id":32},{"id":29},{"id":30}].map(i => i.id))
console.log([{"id":32},{"id":29},{"id":30}].map(i => i.id).join(', '))
```

Which, with your example, is probably going to be:

```
const myList = JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize').map(i => i.id));
```

Comment: Thanks, this did it. I was able to literally copy paste and it worked. I can run through the output in PHP now as an Array.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want an array of numbers, convert that output array of objects to array of numbers

```js
var list = [{"id":32}, {"id":29}, {"id":30}];

var required = list.map(item => item.id);
console.log(required);
```